# Exception while reading from stream ---> System.IO.IOException

Tags: postgresql-13

I use Postgresql-13 in my ASP MVC NET 6 project, occasionally, I face this issue below:

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlReadBuffer.g__EnsureLong|41_0(NpgsqlReadBuffer buffer, Int32 count, Boolean async, Boolean readingNotifications) at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlReadBuffer.g__EnsureLong|41_0(NpgsqlReadBuffer buffer, Int32 count, Boolean async, Boolean readingNotifications) at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt) at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.g__OpenCore|191_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt) at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open() at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command, Action`2 paramReader) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 2847 at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 581 at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 452

my ConnectionString to Postgresql-13 was:

"Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=mydb;User ID=myuserid;Password=mypassword;Keepalive=30; Connection Idle Lifetime=300; Tcp Keepalive=true";

my postgresql.conf

shared_buffers = 256MB

and my sysctl.conf

kernel.shmmax=100663296

why did it happen?, what should I check?

Answer (score 1):

Potential causes are:

- Session had hit an inactivity timeout and was terminated. ==> You can try adding/changing [CommandTimeout parameter to more than default of 30  seconds.](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.html)
- Connection used an authentication token, which had expired.
- Database connection listener service had been restarted, possibly due to patching or automated code deployment. ==> You could add code to reconnect and run a simple "heartbeat" query like SELECT CURRENT_DATE;

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your ssl is not working. You might need the certificate to connection via https to the DB